# Optimizing WHILE and FOR loops in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, optimization

i would like some help with optimizing a piece of code. First, I will provide some context.
I have a DataFrame with 23k rows and 33 columns which represents reservations and another dataframe with 2k rows and 50 columns which represent properties. What I would like happenning is to understand monthly GBV (Gross Booking Value) and monthly booked nights. The tricky part is that "monthly" inclines the following:

If a reservation is from 25th of a month until the 5th of the next month and the ADR (Average Daily Rate) is 50 dollars, the result of this reservation is going to be the following:

Nights Booked in 1st month: 7 nights (from 25th to 31st)
Nights Booked in 2nd month: 5 nights (from 1st to 5th)
GBV for 1st month: 7 nights * 50 dollars = 350 dollars
GBV for 2nd month: 5 nights * 50 dollars = 250 dollars

Sample data would be:
In reservation dataframe: Arrival_date, Departure_date, Accommodation_amount
In properties dataframe: GBV column for each month and Nights booked column for each month

Here is the piece of code that I am using currently:

```
    i=0
while i < len(kpi):
    if kpi['cod_reservation_status'][i] == 'CONF':
        dateRange = pd.date_range(kpi['arrival'][i], kpi['departure'][i], freq='d', closed='left')
        index = prop_index(int(kpi['id_room'][i]), props.id_room_type)
        nGBV = kpi['accommodation_total_amount'][i] / len(dateRange)
        for adate in dateRange:
            if adate.month == 1 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['January Booked'][index] = props['January Booked'][index] + 1
                props['January GBV'][index] = props['January GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 2 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['February Booked'][index] = props['February Booked'][index] + 1
                props['February GBV'][index] = props['February GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 3 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['March Booked'][index] = props['March Booked'][index] + 1
                props['March GBV'][index] = props['March GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 4 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['April Booked'][index] = props['April Booked'][index] + 1
                props['April GBV'][index] = props['April GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 5 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['May Booked'][index] = props['May Booked'][index] + 1
                props['May GBV'][index] = props['May GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 6 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['June Booked'][index] = props['June Booked'][index] + 1
                props['June GBV'][index] = props['June GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 7 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['July Booked'][index] = props['July Booked'][index] + 1
                props['July GBV'][index] = props['July GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 8 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['August Booked'][index] = props['August Booked'][index] + 1
                props['August GBV'][index] = props['August GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 9 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['September Booked'][index] = props['September Booked'][index] + 1
                props['September GBV'][index] = props['September GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 10 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['October Booked'][index] = props['October Booked'][index] + 1
                props['October GBV'][index] = props['October GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 11 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['November Booked'][index] = props['November Booked'][index] + 1
                props['November GBV'][index] = props['November GBV'][index] + nGBV
            if adate.month == 12 and adate.year == 2022:
                props['December Booked'][index] = props['December Booked'][index] + 1
                props['December GBV'][index] = props['December GBV'][index] + nGBV
    i+=1
```

That works and does the job BUT it is quite slow. On 22k entries, it takes me 2 and a half minutes. I am sure there is a way to optimize this. Any ideas are welcome. What are the best practices in optimizing loops and how would you go about this specific task?

PS: kpi = reservations DataFrame, props = properties DataFrame

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results? I know your looking for optimization, but that would help understand the larger scope of the project and help with some code rework as well

Comment: I will provide but tomorrow morning as I have left work and my files are at my work computer. Thank you for taking the time!

Answer (score 2):

With pandas you must not use while and for loop where it is possible to use pandas built-in function which are written in C code and compiled (quicker than interpreted).

Try to uses `props.loc[:,"column"].apply("the function you want to apply")`

With pandas you must think the entire dataset and not iterate objects.

Look into the documnetation for [df.loc[row,col]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try implementing the .apply  and .loc into the function and will share the results.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas, alike Numpy, are thought for vector operations. Avoid as much as you can iterations, think of "block" equations.

Some tips:

- Use constructs like `query` for fast data access, like `df.query("reserved=True")`
- Besides `apply()` you can "explode()" the dateranges: That will create new rows where you can apply operations in parallel (adate = bookeddate)
- ...

With Pandas/Numpy the only point where `for`/`while` loops are encouraged is when using Numba or Cython

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have this:

```
i=0
while i < len(kpi):
```

A `while` loop is slower than a `for` loop. Because a while loop checks the condition after each iteration.

So you should replace it with this:

```
for i in range(len(kpi) - 1)
```

The reason you need to subtract one is because you want `i` to always be smaller than `len(kpi)` because when you use the index of something you start with `0`

Comment: Maybe provide a link or something supporting this? I'd believe it, but "I saw a video that said x" isn't a particularly strong answer.

Comment: For a loop that *does nothing*, `for` is indeed faster than the corresponding `while` loop. But in OP’s code, which loop you choose makes zero difference for performance. (Of course OP should still use a `for` loop simply because it’s more readable.)

Comment: Should I delete my answer then?

Comment: While loops evaluate a condition. A for loop has to call its iterator's `__next__` method; it's not free. In any case, you would rarely, if ever, use `range(len(kpi))` over `enumerate(kpi)`.

Comment: I wrote this few months back and I remember encountering an error when I tried doing the outer loop with for i in range(Len(kpi)) which is why I proceeded with for loop and counter. I also have other parts of my code that need reworking and optimizing but I want to take it one sip at a time.

Comment: Oh yeah that's probably because you need to do this: `for i in range(len(kpi) - 1)` I edited my answer

Comment: Regardless, using `for` or `while` to traverse pandas dateframe should be punishable with jail. It is a failure to understand the whole concept (unless we talk numba)